# Gym Management Software

Tags: gym

I am not able to find any good software for managing a Gym.

Guys, can you help me provide links/reference to any good Gym Management Software which is not so costly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about software recommendations and not fitness.

Comment: You should post your question on the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I'm glad we could help. It's not a bad question, just not one that fits this site.

Comment: @rrirower - Please don't encourage cross posting. Flag for moderator to migrate instead.

Comment: @JohnP Agreed.  But, then, how does he know not to post the same kind of question in the future?

Comment: @rrirower - I generally leave a comment stating "Your question is off topic for this site, but it may fit on another SE site. I've flagged it for the moderator to move it", and theoretically if a moderator migrates it, they should also leave a comment explaining (And then the question links to the new site as well.)

Comment: @JohnP, I have already posted the question on  'Software Recommendations' site. Should I delete this?

Comment: Only if you want, it's already closed here.